# Node.js - throw exception inside ES6 promise chain

Tags: node.js, error-handling, es6-promise, throw

As part of an Node.js/Express API I am developing, I have built a custom error handler that lets me throw specific errors when needed e.g. BadRequest or NotFound etc.

The problem occurs when I wish to throw within a promise chain. For example:

```
db.doSomethingAsync().then(data => {

    if(data.length === 0){
        throw new errors.ResourceNotFound({ resource: "foo" });
    }
});
```

After much reading on the topic, I see that this error will be swallowed by the promise and hence causes an unhandled Promise rejection.

I am aware I can reject however im not sure how I can then handle the specific error (rather than a catchall on reject which I dont want).

Also, to reject, would I not need to create a new promise inside of my promise chain? That feels messy.

Can anyone advise how to handle throwing a specific exception within a promise chain?

Comment: In a promise chain, you return errors by either doing a `throw` or returning a rejected promise.  Either will change the promise chain to a rejected state which you can then handle at a higher level in your promise chain.  Where exactly in the chain to handle the error depends upon what you are trying to accomplish.  But, you MUST handle the rejection in the promise chain somewhere.  Async exceptions can't get caught anywhere else so they serve little useful purpose without handling them somewhere and then deciding what to do when that condition occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the first callback to **then()** which is resolve callback and recieves data, you could also provide a second callback to it which is reject callback and it recieves errors. so you could catch this specific error on the second callback of the next then:

```
db
  .doSomethingAsync()
  .then(data => {
    if(data.length === 0){
        throw new errors.ResourceNotFound({ resource: "foo" });
    }
  })
  .then(massagedData => {
    // work with massagedData here
  }, err => {
    // handle err here which is previous thrown error
    // assert.ok( err instanceof errors.ResourceNotFound() )
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // this will catch unhandled errors if any
  });
```

**then()** by default returns a promise and if any of its callbacks ( whether the first or the second one ) throws an error then it returns a rejected promise and its reason will caught by next reject callback if any or by catch at the end. So you don't need to create a new promise.

See [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)